# How to move s3 objects from one bucket to another based on time of creation using AWS CLI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I have a version enabled bucket "A" with many objects. I need to move all the objects from bucket "A" to another version enabled bucket "B". The condition is "I need to move the objects based on time of creation. The older objects in bucket "A" should be moved first"

How to do this using aws-cli?

Comment: You can't do it in one command. You need write a script for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here it is the single command:

```
aws s3 ls s3://<from-bucket> --recursive | awk '{d=substr($0,1,10)}(d < "2019-10-25")' | cut -c 32- | awk '{print "--include "$0}' ORS=' ' | xargs aws s3 mv s3://<from-bucket> s3://<to-bucket> --recursive --exclude '*'
```

1. first we read all the files from the source bucket and the first column in the output would be the latest change date
2. then using `awk` we subtract the date and compare with a target date you specify by your own
3. using `cut` subtract file names
4. using `awk` prepare include arguments for `aws s3 mv` command
5. using `xargs` pass the arguments to `aws s3 mv`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, will this work for buckets in 2 different accounts? Say version enabled bucket "A" is in one account and version enabled bucket "B" in another account.

Comment: Here is a good example how to do that https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/copy-s3-objects-account